# In Naruto, does the previous host die after Orochimaru changes hosts?

Tags: naruto, boruto

If so, why are there some who are eager to be the next "container"?

> And in Boruto why haven't they stopped Orochimaru from taking new hosts?

Comment: I put the question related to Boruto in a spoiler field. If someone who's more familiar with Naruto feels it should be taken out, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question,Yes. Much like shedding skin of a snake.

They haven't stopped him in Boruto because he is much more useful to them alive.

They know Orochimaru has huge amount of Intel, which would be useful to them in the future. This proved to be true in the Shin Uchiha arc, when he told them who Shin was.

Also, they know that now that Naruto and Sasuke are so much powerful (too OP), Orochimaru wouldn't be a big problem to them.

But to prevent any mishap, they still have put surveillance on him. Captain Yamato was seen keeping an eye on Orochimaru in the Shin Uchiha arc in the anime.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Abhishek's reasoning why they let him do it.

Well, Sasuke might be the pragmatic type who could think "Well, maybe someone dies occasionally but his information could save the village many times."

But Naruto is an ol' Shonen "Save everyone" type of guy. He almost breaks because Neji is killed in the war in front of his eyes, if not for Hinata. Neji was "some kind of"-friend to Naruto, their biggest interaction was during their first Chunin exam and the hunt for Sasuke. Neji was Hinata's cousin and bodyguard and although he had a somewhat rude attitude towards her at the beginning of the series Naruto, that was changed after Naruto beat him up.

Let me emphasize this: Naruto is more emotionally unstable than Hinata. Naruto cares deeply about people, even if it is just some random bridge builder who fooled the village with a mission rank and put Naruto and his team in mortal danger. **There is no way Naruto would accept an occasional offering of a person for the sake of Orochimaru's longevity.**

There are two scenarios I can imagine:

1. Orochimaru found a way to only use beings as sacrifices that don't count as "people" in Naruto's eyes. That could be something like Zetsu clones, brain dead people or maybe Naruto learned of the existence of humans like child abusers and adjusted his morals.
2. The people in charge of Orochimaru, including Sasuke and Yamato, lie to Naruto regarding Orochimaru's practices, so that Orochimaru can continue his work.

It may help that

> Orochimaru's son is in the village's care.